# how to create popup in jade template using either jquery or angularjs

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I am using the Express framework with Jade templating.  My problem is that I want to add a popup. I have both jQuery and Angular. I have tried window popup npm of nodejs but it does not meet my requirement. I want to display a popup on button click.

Comment: hey @Magedev12345 have you tried the proposed solution?

Comment: hi andrea-f First of all thanks for the post. I have started using ejs template now. so didn't got the chance.

Answer (score 1):

In a recent project I was working on, a confirmation popup was needed to confirm whether a user wanted to delete something or not. Since this was the only client side UI interaction, the overhead of moving to browserify and watchify was much greater than the task required. **So this is NOT using either angular or jquery but rather an NPM based plugin.**

Yet, **it achieves the task of creating server side poups with Node Express and Jade.**

First, a plugin for popups was chosen in the npm repository. The chosen was popupS, a NPM based plugin, which uses browserify to be compiled and used.

The plugin can be obtained from:
For Node.js + Browserify installs:

```
npm install popupS --save
```

However it was currently out of scope to use browserify, so the plugin was obtained from the gitHub repo. The following steps identify how to include popups in server side code with Jade, Express and Node:

In the Node app root folder locate the app.js file and make sure a snippet such as this is present:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

The line of code uses the express.static to set a folder for static files. Then in the public directory in the root folder of the Node app, create a js folder.

Then:

```
cd /public/js
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ChiefORZ/popupS/master/dist/popupS.min.js
cd ../css
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ChiefORZ/popupS/master/css/popupS.min.css
```

Then in the app's views, where Jade files are contained, locate the app's index.jade or layout.jade file, where the `body` and `head` tags are located.
    Lets say the head is in `layout.jade`, add the following lines within it:

```
link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/popupS.min.css')
script(src="/js/popupS.min.js")
```

Then in the Jade file where the popup needs to appear add a button with the onClick event calling a js function which in turns creates the popup. The following code shows this:

```
script.
     function popup() {
         popupS.confirm({
             content: 'Do you want to delete #{user.userName}?',
             labelOk: 'Yes',
             labelCancel: 'No',
             onSubmit: function() {
                 window.location.href = "/users/removeUser/#{user._id}"
             },
             onClose: function() {
                 console.log(':(');
             }
        });
     }
td
button(onclick="popup()") Delete with conf
```

The function gets called when the user clicks on the button 'Delete with conf', then a popup is displayed asking the user for confirmation. If the user confirms the browser is redirected to a route which deletes the user object, otherwise nothing happens.
The popup then looks like:
[image]

Even though UI logic should not be in Jade, with only 20 lines of code now there are popups in the application without the overhead of using browserify!

The original blogpost I created is here: [Node Express Jade popups](http://www.walkabout.xyz/2015/11/how-to-create-server-side-popups-with-node-express-and-jade/)

Answer (score 0):

You could attach the `onclick` handler to a link and then open a popup.

```
a(href="http://link-to-open.com/" onclick="window.open(this.href);return false;") Open Popup
```